# Extracting values from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Write R code to

name = c('Anokhi', 'Diya', 'Kapil', 'Joseph', 'Zaroo','Manoj', 'Mayank', 'Lalit', 'Kishor', 'Jaspreet')
score = c(12, 9, 16.5, 12, 9, 20, 14.5, 13.5, 8, 19)
attempts = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 2, NA, 1, 1, 2, 1)
qualify = c('yes', 'no', 'yes',`yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes','yes', 'no','yes')

How can I do the following:
a.  Extract name and score column
b.  Extract first two rows
c.  Extract 3rd and 5th row
d.  Extract 3rd and 5th row with 1st and 3rd column

Comment: Looks like an assignment, can you share what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Library(tidyverse)

exam_data%>%
select(name, score)

exam_data[,1:2]

exam_data[,c(3,5]

exam_data[c(1,3),c(3,5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an assignment, hope you study this solution consciously and learn.

```
exam_data <- 
  data.frame(name = c('Anokhi', 'Diya', 'Kapil', 'Joseph', 'Zaroo','Manoj', 'Mayank', 'Lalit', 'Kishor', 'Jaspreet'), 
  score = c(12, 9, 16.5, 12, 9, 20, 14.5, 13.5, 8, 19), 
  attempts = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 2, NA, 1, 1, 2, 1),
  qualify = c('yes', 'no', 'yes','yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes','yes', 'no','yes'))

exam_result_a <- exam_data[, c('name','score')]
exam_result_b <- exam_data[1:2,]
exam_result_c <- exam_data[c(3,5),]
exam_result_d <- exam_data[c(3,5),c(1,3)]
```